# Youtube Popular videos list in iPhone using data api

Tags: ios, youtube

I want to show the list of popular videos from youtube on the main screen and when i click on any item then it starts playing the video

i want to search and view the videos list without login

Answer (score 0):

you have to use [youtube api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/) to fetch the data as JSON and use `NSJSONSerialization` to split the data into  arrays and use them as you want.